# How to kill nobody session in oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, authentication, session, oracle-apex

When i logged in oracle apex, a session is created in this table "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_SESSIONS$" in oracle apex. but when i logged in it creates session with the username nobody. 
How to kill this user in all situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open your application login page, Apex will create a session in name nobody. It does not know who you are yet. When you login by entering your ID/Password, it will create a new session for you.

You can delete the nobody's session by delete_session procedure if the session belong to your workspace form your Apex designer. e.g.

```
begin
  apex_session.delete_session (
  p_session_id => 2224940013004);
end;
```

Certainly, after doing this, if you still try to login from the login page, it will show you time-out error.

As my opinion, no need to delete nobody session. Apex will do it sometime late.

Best regards.

Cho